# asterisk(*) and dot-asterisk(.*) in unix regular expression

Tags: regex, unix

I am always finding myself confused with the usage of these two wildcards in UNIX. 
I understand asterisk can be used only as a quantifier in a regexp, but UNIX allows `*` in some cases like the `ls` command whereas in `grep` it should be used only as a quantifier. Is there some rule out there which will guide me which one of these to use?

Comment: You are confused between `regex` and `glob`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're talking about two separate kinds of patterns in UNIX, the *glob* (wildcard) and the *regular expression*.

Globs are typically used when matching filenames. Your shell does wildcard expansion automatically on command arguments, which is how you can write

```
ls *foo*
```

to list all files containing the string `foo`. Globs are very simple (ignoring `extglob`): the syntax typically only supports `*` (any characters) and `?` (any one character). Because of the shell's automatic expansion, these can be used anywhere and must be explicitly suppressed to avoid unwanted matching (e.g. writing `grep '.*foo.*'` to avoid expanding the `*` in the pattern).

On the other hand, we have regular expressions, which are used to pattern-match text. Typically, these are used with specific utilities like `grep`, `sed` and `perl` which understand these patterns, though some shells have contexts which take regex (e.g. Bash's `${x/pat/sub}`). Regular expression syntax is much more powerful, which makes it ideal for looking through reams of text for specific patterns.

Comment: That exlpains it clearly! Thank you for taking your time to right this detailed answer.